# SQL Server Deadlock by Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I have the following Table Structure:

```
TableA  
ID, Integer, Clustered PK
<SomeDataColumns>

TableB  
ID, Integer, Clustered PK
<SomeDataColumns>

TableC  
ID, IDENTITY, Clustered PK  
A_ID, Integer, FK referencing TableA(ID)  
B_ID, Integer, FK referencing TableB(ID)
```

TableC(A_ID, B_ID) is a non-clustered unique index

I have N (N >=2) separate Processes, which execute the following query:

```
UPDATE TableC
Set A_ID = 123
WHERE A_ID = 456 AND B_ID = 789
```

This results in a deadlock scenario:

```
<deadlock>
 <victim-list>
  <victimProcess id="process201c7713c28" />
 </victim-list>
 <process-list>
  <process id="process201c7713c28" taskpriority="0" logused="832" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057594924695552 (a92c94fd9b5a)" waittime="469" ownerId="3263033" transactionname="UPDATE" lasttranstarted="2022-01-03T21:06:15.257" XDES="0x2015d9c0428" lockMode="U" schedulerid="9" kpid="29356" status="suspended" spid="60" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2022-01-03T21:06:15.257" lastbatchcompleted="2022-01-03T21:06:15.087" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.087" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostpid="22480" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="3263033" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="96" stmtend="362" sqlhandle="0x02000000210386281ce81d1cbb16a73fd65d75f4ba0bf9890000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
(@NextStep int,@PreviousStep int,@ProcessId int)update TableC with (rowlock) set A_ID = @NextStep where A_ID = @PreviousStep and B_ID = @ProcessId   </inputbuf>
  </process>
  <process id="process201c707b088" taskpriority="0" logused="1302024" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057594924695552 (d966faef42b0)" waittime="469" ownerId="3262982" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2022-01-03T21:06:05.867" XDES="0x201bc150428" lockMode="U" schedulerid="6" kpid="24392" status="suspended" spid="53" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2022-01-03T21:06:15.257" lastbatchcompleted="2022-01-03T21:06:15.257" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.257" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostpid="22288" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="3262982" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="96" stmtend="362" sqlhandle="0x02000000210386281ce81d1cbb16a73fd65d75f4ba0bf9890000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
(@NextStep int,@PreviousStep int,@ProcessId int)update TableC with (rowlock) set A_ID = @NextStep where A_ID = @PreviousStep and B_ID = @ProcessId   </inputbuf>
  </process>
 </process-list>
 <resource-list>
  <keylock hobtid="72057594924695552" dbid="5" objectname="dbo.TableC" indexname="PK_TableC" id="lock20174f25800" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594924695552">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process201c707b088" mode="X" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process201c7713c28" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </keylock>
  <keylock hobtid="72057594924695552" dbid="5" objectname="dbo.TableC" indexname="PK_TableC" id="lock20184c7a700" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594924695552">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process201c7713c28" mode="X" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process201c707b088" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </keylock>
 </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

The updated rows by different processes are always distinct.

The Deadlock Scenario is immediatly "solved", if I remove the Foreign Key Constraint from TableC(A_ID) -> TableA(ID), which suggests, that 1 Lock is for the update of TableC, while the other one is for integrity checking against TableA? However in my understanding that should not collide, because the integrity can be checked via Index Seek.

I want to understand, what is happening and why?

Comment: do you have CASCADE UPDATES on?

Comment: @MitchWheat No, I dont. Its set to "No Action".

Comment: Did you make transaction scope on your script and what are indexes in your  `tableC`

Comment: `<process id="process201c707b088" logused="1302024" ... lasttranstarted="2022-01-03T21:06:05.867" ... lastbatchstarted="2022-01-03T21:06:15.257" >` - looks like that process is doing other stuff in the same transaction before it gets to the statement you have shown us. What else runs in the same tran? Also the deadlocked resources are only on `PK_TableC` anyway. One tran has a `U` lock on a key and requests an `X` lock on a different key and vice versa

Comment: +1 for providing the deadlock graph, but this is not answerable without also the full queries involved (including anything else in the transaction) and the execution plans (via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan). Are there any indexes other than the PKs, please provide?

Comment: You probably need an index `TableC (B_ID, A_ID)` and arguably `TableC` should have that as its primary key and not have a separate `IDENTITY` column